# PyInstaller does NOT work when including Pysnmp

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, pysnmp

Just trying one of the official documentation site examples:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
          CommunityData('public'),
          UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.1.14', 161)),
          ContextData(),
          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (
           errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
           errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'
       )
    )
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
       print(' = '.join([ x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind ]))
```

we can see it does work if its executed through the Python interpreter:

```
 (Compiler)[user@machine testSNMP]$ python testSNMP.py 
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr."0" = 48-port 10/100/1000 Gigabit Switch
```

However, if I try to "freeze" it with PyInstaller (PyInstaller --onefile) I get the following error once it is executed:

```
  (Compiler)[user@machine testSNMP]$ /lab/testSNMP/dist/testSNMP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.entity.engine", line 83, in __init__
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.smi.builder", line 359, in importSymbols
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: No module __SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB loaded at <pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder instance at 0x179f518>
```

It seems that mandatory files in pysnmp/smi/mibs are not explicitly imported to be used. That's why I've split the build procedure in phases. Fist, create the spec file.

```
(Compiler)[user@machine testSNMP]$ pyi-makespec --onefile getInterfaces.py
wrote /lab/testSNMP/getInterfaces.spec
now run pyinstaller.py to build the executable
```

Then, I've edited it to import required files following advices from this other stack post ([Can't get pysnmp to work with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838777/cant-get-pysnmp-to-work-with-pyinstaller)):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils
hiddenimports = ['pysnmp.smi.exval','pysnmp.cache'] + PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils.collect_submodules('pysnmp.smi.mibs') + PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils.collect_submodules('pysnmp.smi.mibs.instances')
a = Analysis(['testSNMP.py'],
            pathex=['/lab/testSNMP'],
            hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
            hookspath=None,
            runtime_hooks=None)
x = Tree('/virtualenvs/Compiler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs',prefix='pysnmp/smi/mibs',excludes='.py')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
         a.scripts,
         a.binaries,
         a.zipfiles,
         a.datas,
         x,
         name='testSNMP',
         debug=False,
         strip=None,
         upx=True,
         console=True )
```

But then, once it's built and executed, I'm getting this other error:

```
(Compiler)[user@machine testSNMP]$ /lab/testSNMP/dist/testSNMP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore.sync.cmdgen", line 98, in getCmd
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore.cmdgen", line 135, in getCmd
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.hlapi.varbinds", line 30, in makeVarBinds
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.smi.rfc1902", line 689, in resolveWithMib
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.smi.rfc1902", line 299, in resolveWithMib
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysnmp.smi.compiler", line 44, in addMibCompiler
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysmi.parser.smi", line 21, in __init__
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysmi.lexer.smi", line 83, in __init__
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/pysmi.lexer.smi", line 100, in reset
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/ply.lex", line 915, in lex
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/ply.lex", line 577, in validate_all
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/ply.lex", line 819, in validate_rules
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/ply.lex", line 830, in validate_module
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/inspect", line 690, in getsourcelines
  File "/lab/testSNMP/build/testSNMP/out00-PYZ.pyz/inspect", line 538, in findsource
IOError: could not get source code
```

What else can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding the following to get better debugging output. 'from pysnmp import debug
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('mibbuild'))'

Answer (score 2):

To make Jeremy's answer portable, you can modify your specfile like this diff:

```
+ import os.path
+ import pysmi
+ import pysnmp.smi.mibs

+ def module_base(module):
+   return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(module.__file__, os.pardir))

  coll = COLLECT(
      exe,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
+     Tree(module_base(pysmi), prefix='pysmi'),
+     Tree(module_base(pysnmp.smi.mibs), prefix='pysnmp/smi/mibs'),
      ...
```

EDIT:
turn out adding these to hiddenimports solved the problem for me:

```
'pysnmp.smi.mibs', 'pysnmp.smi.mibs.instances', 'pysnmp.smi.exval', 'pysnmp.cache'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to get it working by including the `pysmi` files as a Tree just like the pysnmp mibs.

My pyinstaller spec file ended up like:

```
...

x = Tree(os.getcwd()+'/.pyenv/Lib/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs',prefix='pysnmp/smi/mibs')
y = Tree(os.getcwd()+'/.pyenv/Lib/site-packages/pysmi',prefix='pysmi')

...

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      x,y,

...
```

While this worked I actually solved it in another way by using an older version of pysnmp v4.2.5 which doesn't depend on pysmi

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error "could not get source code". There is an issue about that created on Pyinstaller github page:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1945
Solution is to include ply to spec file as it is described in link you mentioned:
[Can't get pysnmp to work with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838777/cant-get-pysnmp-to-work-with-pyinstaller)
by adding "PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules('ply')" to hiddenimports

And make sure ply version is >= 3.9!

My spec file looks pretty much same except Analysis part:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files('pysnmp') + \
         hiddenimports=PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules('pysmi')+\
         PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules('ply') + \
         PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules('pyasn1') + \
         PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules('pysnmp'),
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```