# Problems when packaging pysnmp with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, pysnmp

When I tried to use `pyinstaller` to package my `pysnmp` based code to exe file, I met the same problem as described in [PyInstaller does NOT work when including Pysnmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944919/pyinstaller-does-not-work-when-including-pysnmp/49194434#49194434)
However, after I changed the spec file as suggested, I got another error:

```
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI124682\python36.dll'. 
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm using `windows 10, Python3.6.4-32bit`
I'm very confused, can anybody tell me where could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Today it finally works. I used a 32-bit python 3.6.4 before, now I downloaded a 64-bit python 3.6.4, and it works, although I don't know why. My windows is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to coutingstar's above answer if nothing seems to work out for this issue uninstall and reinstall the version of python that matches your os version and then try the same steps.