# MibnotfoundError with Pyinstaller using pysnmp

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, pysnmp

I created a code to read snmp data, however, once the Executive files generated with pyinstaller, generates me this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkQfl.png)

thanks for any replies

Comment: I can see similar questions at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838777/cant-get-pysnmp-to-work-with-pyinstaller, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944919/pyinstaller-does-not-work-when-including-pysnmp

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen and with their suggestions I can not make it work anyway. Thanks for the answer